# Why mi ListBox is not recovering Focus?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a `TextBox` with a `ListBox` just below that acts as an autocomplete TextBox. For a better explanation, it would be great if you look at [this](http://youtu.be/LHwcGRheW30) video.

This is my code:

**The xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox 
        Name="TextAuto"
        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        PreviewKeyDown="TextAuto_OnPreviewKeyDown" />

    <ListBox Name="ListBoxSuggestion"
             Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Visibility="Collapsed" 
             PreviewKeyDown="ListBoxSuggestion_OnPreviewKeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

**The code behind:**

```C#
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    nameList = new List<string>
    {
        "A0-Word", "B0-Word", "C0-Word",
        "A1-Word", "B1-Word", "C1-Word",
        "A2-Word", "B2-Word", "C2-Word",
        "A3-Word", "B3-Word", "C3-Word"
    };
    TextAuto.TextChanged += TextAuto_TextChanged;
}

void TextAuto_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string typedString = TextAuto.Text;
    List<string> autoList = new List<string>();
    autoList.Clear();

    autoList.AddRange(nameList.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextAuto.Text)).Where(item => item.StartsWith(typedString)));

    if (autoList.Count > 0)
    {
        ListBoxSuggestion.ItemsSource = autoList;
        ListBoxSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else 
    {
        ListBoxSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ListBoxSuggestion.ItemsSource = null;
    }
}

private void TextAuto_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsDown || e.Key != Key.Down) return;

    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, ListBoxSuggestion);
    ListBoxSuggestion.SelectedIndex = 0;

}

private void ListBoxSuggestion_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsDown && e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        if (ListBoxSuggestion.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            ListBoxSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            TextAuto.TextChanged -= TextAuto_TextChanged;
            if (ListBoxSuggestion.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                TextAuto.Text = ListBoxSuggestion.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
            TextAuto.TextChanged += TextAuto_TextChanged;
        }
    }

    if (!e.IsDown || e.Key != Key.Up) return;
    if (ListBoxSuggestion.SelectedIndex != 0) return;

    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, TextAuto);
    ListBoxSuggestion.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

When in the `TextBox`, if down pressed you access the `ListBox`. In the `ListBox`, when going up, if the `SelectedIndex==0`, I give the focus back to the `TextBox`. But second time I want to give the focus back to the `ListBox` (second time I press **down key** inside the `TextBox`), the `ListBox` looks gray, and I can't access it... :(

But, as appreciated in the video, it seems as the ListBox never recovers the focus!! But when looking to the `FocusManager.FocusedElement`, it says the **ListBox** has the focus. Same happens with the `Keyboard.Focus`.

What can be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `IsTabStop="False"` to your TextBox

```
<TextBox 
    Name="TextAuto"
    Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    PreviewKeyDown="TextAuto_OnPreviewKeyDown" IsTabStop="False" />
```

It's basically getting TabFocused for some odd reason.  Because Down Key is use to select objects on the Page as well.